# Reading file c with different choices?

Tags: c

I have some question I want to ask about reading file. I have a 
 data.txt file like this:

```
 [1]
    1abcd)*^$!"   
    Data2 qe
    [2]
```

here is my code:

```
 #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<ctype.h>
    #include<string.h>
    void Input()
    {
        int n;
        char s[20];
        char*word;
        errno_t err;
        FILE *fp;
        err = fopen_s(&fp, "data.txt", "rt");
        while (!feof(fp))
        {
            fgets(s, 20, fp);
            char *word = strtok(s, "[]");
            if (word[strlen(word) -1] == '1')
            {
                fgets(s, 20, fp);
                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
                {
                    if (isgraph((int)s[i]))
                    {
                        printf("%c", s[i]);
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
                {
                    if (iscntrl((int)s[i]))
                    {
                        printf("%c", s[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        Input();
        return 0;
    }
```

Now  I can read what include in [1], it has 2 lines, and then I want the first line to apply  function `isgraph()`, second line to apply function `iscntrl()`.

My first question is how can we read each line and apply it with different function like I said above?

And second question is what if I read all lines and apply them with just one function like is `isgraph()` for example?

The last question is what if I just read [1], and the program automatically run functions for each lines in [1], and similar with [2],[3], *etc.*

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. Why did you add the tag for an unrelated language?

Comment: For your first question: Just read the next line, i.e. add `fgets(s, 20, fp);` before the second loop. (btw - you should check the return value of fgets). Unfortunately the two other questions are unclear to me. Can you explain in more details.

Comment: @4386427 yo man ,thank you ,you rock LUL

Comment: @Olaf well i think ,C/C++ is not different much , my bad

Comment: @4386427 second question i want to use one function like is graph for all the line i read ,i.e. 
[1] 
dsa43
d34gh5SFSAF
23432
like u see i want to use all 3 lines above with 1 fucntion isgraph()
My third question ,i.e
[1]
adsa
bbbb
[2]
346
aaa

like u see,when i read [1],2 lines will be read,then what i want is if i have 2 functions,the first function will automatically run with line 1,second will run with line 2 without reading each line ,like i did in my above code.

Comment: >ou trhink wrong. Read the standards, they are quite different languages.

Comment: What text or who suggested using `while (!feof(fp))`?

Comment: @chux ,what 's wrong with it man??i read from a c/c++ instruction book  i buy from bookstore

Comment: `feof(fp)` reports if end-of-file happened _in the past_.  It does not indicate if the following `fgets()`.  will read anything.  Check the return value of `fgets()` to determine if anything was read.  code rarely needs the `feof()` function.  This code certainly does not need `foef()`.

Comment: @chux thanks man , after searching about feof ,i understand now